# EXCEL Character encoding

Tags: excel, character-encoding

I'm trying to paste 16 digits no. in excel "4132664401073253", however when I paste it it's not the same as what I copied the data change  ->"4132664401073250" the last digits **replace with 0**.
How can I solve this?

Comment: This is not an encoding problem, it's the number precision in excel. Paste the number as a string if you can, i.e. you don't need to do calculations based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **Formula Bar** and type a single quote (apostrophe).  Then paste the value into the **Formula Bar** after the quote.

Answer (score 0):

For a column of entries, format the column as Text and when pasting use Paste Special..., Text.